# How do I do a swan dive?

Tags: rise-of-the-tomb-raider

For the `No Guts, No Glory` trophy, I have to perform a 2.5 second swan dive. I've done them before, but I'm not sure how... What do I do to make Lara do a swan dive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just after jumping off the ledge, press the key to dive under water (Left Click on PC, not sure what the controls are on consoles).  If she stays standing and just tucks her arms in, you hit the button too late.

Comment: Ah, I'm on PS4, so it'd be L2, but that definitely is not a key that crossed my mind, so thank you! I'll test this when I get home.

Comment: @Vemonus: Yeah, it wasn't the first thing I would have guessed either, but I suppose it does make some sense.  Glad it helped!